# unable to install mongodb properly on ubuntu 17.04

Tags: apt, repository, 17.04, mongodb

I'm getting errors in my terminal every time I try to `apt-get install` something or `update`. I guess it has something to do with installing mongodb.

I'm new to Linux, and I followed this guide exactly on how to install it. I couldn't find a guide for 17.04 version so I did the 16.10, and now every time I try to `apt-get` something I get this error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
W: GPG error: http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/debian wheezy/mongodb-org/3.0
Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 9ECBEC467F0CEB10 W: The repository 'http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/debian wheezy/mongodb-org/3.0 Release' is not signed.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Plus I have an alert in my top bar:

> an error occured please run package manager from the right-click menu or apt-get in a terminal to see what is wrong
>   the error message was :
>
> ```
> Error brokenCount > 0. this usually means that your installed packages have unmet dependencies.
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Run this command:

`sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 0C49F3730359A14518585931BC711F9BA15703C6`

Then

```
sudo apt-add-repository 'deb [ arch=amd64,arm64 ] http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/3.4 multiverse'
```

Then

`sudo apt update`

Comment: Then run `sudo apt -f install`

Comment: Err:6 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                           Could not resolve 'dl.google.com'
Err:7 http://repository.spotify.com stable InRelease                   
  Could not resolve 'repository.spotify.com'
Err:8 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/3.4 InRelease
  Could not resolve repo.mongodb.org http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/debian/dists/wheezy/mongodb-org/3.0/InRelease  Could not resolve 'repo.mongodb.org'
W: Failed to fetch http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu/dists/xenial/mongodb-org/3.4/InRelease  Could not resolve 'repo.mongodb.org'

Comment: That's network problem :D

Comment: it's not , after running sudo apt -f install : Unpacking mongodb-org-tools (3.4.4) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/mongodb-org-tools_3.4.4_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/bin/bsondump', which is also in package mongo-tools 3.2.11-1
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/mongodb-org-tools_3.4.4_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Comment: You should delete `repo.mongodb.org/apt/debian/dists/wheezy/mongodb-org/3.0/…` from your repository

Comment: how do i delete it ?

Comment: Go to settings and select software&updates, select 2nd tab , you'll see it there

Comment: still nothing worked after apt update i tried apt upgrade and i got You might want to run apt --fix-broken install' to correct these
The following packages have unmet dependencies
 mongodb-org : Depends: mongodb-org-tools but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages 
or specify a solutioni tried doing the apt--fix i got this error dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/mongodb-org-tools_3.4.4_amd64.deb --unpack /var/cache/apt/archives/mongodb-org-tools_3.4.4_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1

Comment: E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Comment: run `sudo apt purge mongo*` and try again